# How to measure the rendered size an HTML-element so it fits the rendered size of another with Java?

Tags: java, html, css, epub

How can an html-element's rendered size be "measured" in order to resize it to fit strictly defined dimensions?

I'm writing a java-program that generates / manipulates CSS-formatted HTML-files. There is an template HTML-file that is parsed, and by id of a HTML-element in the DOM its text content is replaced by a translation of itself and the altered HTML-file is saved to disk again.

Now, the translated version of the content might differ in length from the original (different string length, letters sized differently, different writing system used). For design reasons the overall displayed element should have the same size as the original text. So, manually I would adjust the related CSS attribute until I see that the size is right. How would you measure this in a java program? The HTML files will be eBook pages (epub format) therefore, as far as I know, I cannot test my logic this on the final rendering-engine (of e.g. an eBook reading device).

Simplified example: say, there is an element: `<div id="testId1">hello world</div>` and I know that this element with text "hello world" is taking up the right amount of screen space. Now I change the text to "bonjour le monde" (french translation) which is longer, therefore, taking up too much horizontal screen-space. I need to read out the size of "hello world" and decrease the size of "bonjour le monde" until it has the same size as "hello world".

Comment: Java? Or JavaScript?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Java, if anyhow possible. Do you have an approach for javascript in mind?

Comment: java : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info  javascript : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info . which one ? both ? of course, javascript here :)  see offetWidth if that is the hint you ask for

Comment: my comment must have been unclear. My question is about java (the popular high-level programming language). However, if someone had an approach in mind that will only work in javascript (the high-level, dynamic, multi-paradigm, object-oriented, prototype-based, weakly-typed, and interpreted language) I would be interested in that too. But for clarity's sake let's keep this Java only.

Comment: javascript seems to be the language to use for that job (on the fly on the user side)  : possibly an example of what you want to do :  https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/LYVBVve

Comment: @G-Cyrillus yes, this is defenitely interesting, thanks for the link. I will have to look if the EPUB standard / the eBook reading devices support this kind of wizardry. I'm afraid they don't (Usually you're restricted to a very basic, pre-HTML5/CSS3 subset of HTML and CSS).